# What's a good C++ framework for 3D animation?

Tags: c++, framework, 3d, animation, gui-builder

I'm going to be developing a medium-sized application for some research for my Master's degree. The application will be a tool for creating **3D animation**, with some secret sauce mixed in. The tool doesn't need to be industrial-strength; it's just going to be a **proof-of-concept**. It's more important that I have the ability to rapidly create a **GUI** and avoid reinventing the wheel as much as possible. I've already created a pre-prototype with web technologies (HTML, JavaScript, [Three.js](http://threejs.org/), [Webix](http://webix.com/)) which worked very well, however, I'd like to improve my **C++** skills with this next prototype. I'd like to be able to compile to **Windows** and **Linux** (I think our animation lab computers have Red Hat).

Right now, [QT](http://www.qt.io/) is at the top of my list because it's cross-platform and has pretty good GUI-building tools. Unfortunately, I don't believe there is very much built-in support for 3D graphics.

I've also found the [Cinder](http://libcinder.org/) framework, which includes a few 3D graphics classes, but I don't know whether it can be easily used with a GUI framework.

Is there a solution (or combination of solutions) which has these abilities?